# Can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(

Tags: android

I am updating my app to bring it into line with the new permissions model in Android 6.0. Having updated my build.gradle file however I am now getting this compile message which is stopping the build:

```
Warning:com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
```

My build.grade is here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myspace.ian.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 65
        versionName "3.21"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/logback-android-1.1.1-3.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

...and here is my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.dom925.xxxx {
   public *;
}
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.** {*;}
-dontwarn javax.mail.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceService
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

Can anyone help? (I'm a relative noob!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

This is very out of date. Either:

- Update to the latest Play Services (or, better yet, individual artifacts for the pieces of Play Services that you are using), or
- Downgrade your `compileSdkVersion` to something that `6.5.87` will support

As it stands, you are using old Play Services code that is expecting some older version of the Android SDK, not `compileSdkVersion 23`, where `setLatestEventInfo()` no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated to com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 and that seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The 'setLatestEventInfo' method is not supported anymore. Try to use the NotificationBuilder for creating the notifications.

Comment: I'm not using setLatestEventInfo anywhere (and never did) - I already use NotificationBuilder