# getting warning when generating signed APK

Tags: java, android

I am not able to generate signed APK, because of getting the following warning:

> org.acra.ErrorReporter: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo()' in library class android.app.Notification    2.there were 1 unresolved reference to library class members.3. Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: add your code .

Comment: @jitendra namde Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320299/cant-find-referenced-method-void-setlatesteventinfo

Comment: -dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.*

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

Comment: @Dhanshri i am not using any google play service

Comment: Add this in your proguard-rules.pro file:
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceService @jitendra namde

Comment: change this things into app level gradle file ::   minifyEnabled false

Comment: @AndroidTeam if we keep minifyEnabled false then how we can secure our project code

Comment: @Dhanshri i have added but issue not resolve

Comment: if you not want our project code secure then used other wise keep those class that have imported methods.

Comment: @AndroidTeam i want keep my project code secure please explan me steps for that.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt I am not using  google play service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatBase refers to android.app.Notification # setLatestEventInfo. You can build against a later version of the Android runtime (one that does contain this method), or you can indeed suppress the warning:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

or

```
-dontwarn android.app.Notification
```

If this doesn't seem to work, you should double-check that the configuration file is read (e.g. by adding a bogus option).

Comment: I integrate above funtion.Now its working fine!Thank you

Comment: you are welcome.can you please accept this answer?@jitendra namde